# Linq GroupBy is producing duplicate keys

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm attempting to group on two fields in a simple list:

```
Dim pp = From kk In e1
    Group kk By key = New With {kk.enquiry_id, kk.name} Into grouping=Group
    Select key, grouping.tolist, grouping.count
```

However when I pp.dump() (I'm using LinqPad) each key value has just one item in grouping.tolist, grouping.count is always 1 and keys are duplicated.

Isn't the whole point of the key in a Group By that each key is returned only once with all matching items?

Comment: what type for this fields: `kk.enquiry_id`, `kk.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET you have to specify the key(s) of anonymous types:

```
Dim pp = From kk In e1
    Group kk By key = New With {
        Key .enquiry_id = kk.enquiry_id, 
        Key .name = kk.name
    } Into grouping = Group
    Select New With {.key = key, .groupList = grouping.ToList(), .count = grouping.Count()}
```

More infos at: [Anonymous Types (Visual Basic): Key Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

> **Key properties** differ from non-key properties in several fundamental
>   ways:

- Only the values of key properties are compared in order to determine whether two instances are equal.
- The values of key properties are read-only and cannot be changed.
- Only key property values are included in the compiler-generated hash code algorithm for an anonymous type.

In C# all properties of an anonymous type are keys automatically and you can't change that.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for that.  Didn't spot that in any of the documentation.